# Datatable Jquery Individual Column filter/search

Tags: jquery, search, filter, datatable

I want to have a search for all columns in my table. I tried a lot but is not working. What is missing here?

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tt</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js">   </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/demo_table.css" media="screen"  />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#table_id').dataTable().columnFilter();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: i want result like this,but i can not do http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Comment: you can you my filter plugin https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the column filter plugin if you are not using the default column filter.

jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html

After including the plugin, try specifying something like below,

```
  $('#example').dataTable({
             bJQueryUI: true,
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
})


  .columnFilter({  null,  null});
```